# Connect by prior - show parent record in result set also

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code

```
select column from Table 
start with supervisor_id='555555' 
connect by prior employee_id=supervisor_id
```

So this query gives me the result for all the employees that have `55555` as their `supervisor_id` and any other employees that have those `employee_id` as their `supervisor_id`, but I also want the person with the `user_id` = `555555` to show up in my result too, and he has to show up in the same column as if he is part of the result of the query. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The hierarchical query doesn't just return rows - it returns rows IN HIERARCHICAL ORDER. Do you care about that? If you do, the UNION ALL or SELECT DISTINCT solutions posted already may not work - they may change the order of rows in the output. That can be fixed - but first please state whether you care or not.

Answer (score 1):

Put an OR condition and it should work.

See demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ef7f9/1

```
 Select distinct *
from table1 
start with supervisor_id='555555' or employee_id='555555'
connect by prior employee_id=supervisor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could union the supervisor into the query:

```
select column from Table where user_id='555555'
union all
select column from Table 
start with supervisor_id='555555' 
connect by prior employee_id=supervisor_id
```

I'm assuming that the person with `user_id = '555555'` comes from `Table` also and you want to display the same `column` - if not substitute those changes you need into the above SQL.